# hug can't read environment variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, hug

I'm trying to use a environment variables with hug. However, I can't.

first step how i did:

```
$ export INTEGER=5
```

I have this in my main code:

```
import hug
import os


@hug.get('/')
def foo():
   var = os.environ['INTEGER']
   return {'INT':var}
```

when i execute

```
sudo hug -p 80 -f foo.py
```

and go to `localhost/`

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/Users/Andres/.local/share/virtualenvs/botCS-HzHaMvtf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/falcon/api.py", line 244, in __call__
    responder(req, resp, **params)
  File "/Users/Andres/.local/share/virtualenvs/botCS-HzHaMvtf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hug/interface.py", line 734, in __call__
    raise exception
  File "/Users/Andres/.local/share/virtualenvs/botCS-HzHaMvtf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hug/interface.py", line 709, in __call__
    self.render_content(self.call_function(input_parameters), request, response, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Andres/.local/share/virtualenvs/botCS-HzHaMvtf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hug/interface.py", line 649, in call_function
    return self.interface(**parameters)
  File "/Users/Andres/.local/share/virtualenvs/botCS-HzHaMvtf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hug/interface.py", line 100, in __call__
    return __hug_internal_self._function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "repro.py", line 7, in foo
    var = os.environ['INTEGER']
  File "/Users/Andres/.local/share/virtualenvs/botCS-HzHaMvtf/bin/../lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'INTEGER'
```

what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are running `hug` as `sudo` (something you should never do btw.) and adding environment variable as you (a normal user).

I'm guessing that you are running as sudo because you want to run on port 80. Run it rather on port 8080.

---

So this works:

**shell:**

```
export INTEGER=5
```

**python code:**

```
import os

@hug.get('/')
def view():
    print(os.environ['INTEGER'])  # or print(os.environ.get('INTEGER'))
```

**shell:**

```
hug -f app.py -p 8080
```

Comment: if i want to run on port 80, i need to use `sudo`. Anyway, it works your answer on port 8080. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

`os.environ['INTEGER']` fails because `os.environ` has no key called "`INTEGER`".

You can use this code, and provide an optional default as the second arg to `get`:

`os.environ.get("INTEGER", 0)`

This will return `0` (or whatever default you supply) if `INTEGER` is not found.

The reason `INTEGER` is missing must be related to where you defined your bash variable. It must be "in scope" or accessible to the script based on where you are running the script.

Comment: In first step i did `$ export INTEGER=5`. Your answer is work but it returns `0`. I need a `5`